# How to change an already set SVG attribute

Tags: svg, setattribute

I have to modify an SVG element designed by an artist. Attributes "fill" and "stroke" are already set, for the sole purpose that the artist needs to see it while they are designing.

However when I load the SVG and I try to change the element's "fill" and "stroke", `setAttribute("fill", "rgb("255,0,0"))` does not change the color

However, if I ask the artist to unset the `fill` of that element then `setAttribute` works. However, the artist complains that they cannot work with invisible elements nor they want to remember to unset all the fills everytime they need to edit the SVG.

Is there a way to programatically clean or force the attributes of the elements to allow `setAttribute` to work?

PS. I tried to create an example code in w3schools, but it works fine there. I think my problem has to do with the fact that the SVG is an external document and I'm accessing it's elements with `getSVGDocument()`. But I don't know how to create an example because that would require a web server which I don't have.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the svg code? You can change directly in that

Comment: I need to change it dynamically, the fill color of the element is a status indicator.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code example, i hope you'll find it useful

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle
    id="circle1"
    cx="50"
    cy="50"
    r="40"
    stroke="green"
    stroke-width="4"
    fill="red"
   />
</svg>

<button onclick="circle1.style.fill='yellow';">
  Click to change to yellow
</button>
```

This is working for me

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head but kinda accidentally :D

fill was not set as an attribute (like in your example), it is set as a style. 

In your example both setAttribute and style.fill= works

but in my case only style.fill works, because fill was not set as attribute but as style 

I didn't know that changing one style parameter was so easy!

Thank you !